# CasperJS: execution time with slimerjs is significantly lower than with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

I have written an automated web scraping process which navigates to a series of 5 pages and scrapes the required information.

I tried running the script using SlimerJS to make the debugging easy. The execution time of the entire process was less than 15 seconds. I tried multiple times with same results.

Then I tried running it with PhantomJS. Surprisingly, the execution time increased significantly. It was over 35 seconds every time.

I was hoping PhantomJS to be much faster since there is no opening of any GUI. How can I debug why its taking much longer in PhantomJS?

If I am not able to make it faster in PhantomJS, is it advisable to use SlimerJS in production server with headless setup ?

Running these scripts on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Just wanted to say that I am using SlimmerJS in headless mode using xvfb-run in production server to automate some heavy checks and it works really well. In my case, I cann't use phantom because it doesnt support XSLT processing.